# how to add an object to a document in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my code, I get an object from an existing Firebase collection and then I want to add it to another document as an object, however I don't understand how to do it

```
  // Create a query against the collection.
const q = query(subjectRef, where("Subject", "==", subject), where("Board", "==", examBoard), where("Level", "==", level));
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    //add a document to a subcollection in the collection users
    const auth = getAuth();
    //editted so onAuthState function is not called
    const uid = auth.currentUser.uid
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
    const colRef = collection(docRef, "subjects");
    addDoc(colRef, {
      //?????
    });
  })
```

the doc would be added to the collection subjects, this is what the doc looks like:
[image: collection subject > document]
and the structure of the users is (collection) users > (document) user > (collection) subjects > (document) what i want to add

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an onAuthStateChanged observer within a document snapshot observer.  You should know who the signed in user is before you do any queries.

Comment: Have you tried following [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)? Why are you creating an `onAuthStateChanged` listener in every doc for your `subjectRef` query? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @b2m9 i have tried following the documentation however unfortunately it did not help :( and i created the listener to get the uid

Comment: @sakshi you can use `auth.currentUser.uid` to get the uid without calling the `onAuthChanged` Function

Comment: @DougStevenson i had it to get the uid because the console showed errors when i did not have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user ID from `auth.currentUser.uid` property. Here's how you would achieve this:

```
const q = query(subjectRef, where("Subject", "==", subject), where("Board", "==", examBoard), where("Level", "==", level));
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    //add a document to a subcollection in the collection users
    const auth = getAuth();
    var q = doc.data()
    const colRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid,"subjects");
    addDoc(colRef, {
      Board:q.Board
      Level:q.Level
      Subject:q.Subject
    });
    });
```